# Vidalia for OS X?

Tags: vidalia, mac

Where is Vidalia for OS X?  I remember a while ago I had Vidalia, but then updated to TBB, and Vidalia isn't in TBB? I've looked all around Tor's website for a download, but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Vidalia isn't really supported anymore these days. There simply aren't any volunteers working on it and the development focus is now on a different approach to use Tor.

This is the current stage. It *might* change should there be any developers willing to continue the project. However currently this doesn't appear to be the case. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @meee mentioned, Vidalia hasn't been maintained for many years now and is officially dead. And it's not anywhere on the roadmap to come back to life again, so better stick with the latest Tor Browser. If you want to try the sexy new features, you need to get the Alpha version of the Tor Browser.